# 403 Forbidden Error after Apache Update

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04, http-status-code-403

I have several vhosts all of which except 1 are working fine after many packages were upgraded on Ubuntu 16.04 server. The only difference between working and non-working vhosts is that the non-working vhost root directory is a sub directory of another working vhost as opposed to a direct sub directory of root. Working vhosts also do not have the directory directive but even without it non-working vhosts are still just that.

What I have tried/checked:

- Root and all subdirectories have www-data:www-data ownership.
- All sub directories have at least read and execute permissions.
- Tried creating index.html with chmod 777.
- Rebooted the server.

Apache logs only show error below for every attempted file access.

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: [dir_name_here]
```

Vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin **********@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/data/***/files/***

        <Directory "/var/www/owncloud/data/***/files/***/images">
          Options +Indexes
          AllowOverride all
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerName      ***.***.com
        ServerAlias     www.***.***.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=301]

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.***.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.***.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

What could be causing this? What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi have you checked rewrite module is enabled sudo a2enmod rewrite?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana I have now, and yes it was enabled.

Comment: Inside enabled sites folder the config file soft link is there right?

Comment: Yes, I tried disabling in case  of some conflict and then re-enabled it so it is present in sites-enabled now and I even rebooted since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

With

```
Require all granted
```

In apache 2.4 the above lines are deprecated and replaced with following and if you need any help after you updated the apache this doc contains the differences [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html)

Comment: That was it, thanks! Can you add an explanation why it worked and why it worked before but an update broke it?

Comment: It was because apache 2.4 does not support those methods they are deprecated in new version. There was a doc by apache server but i couldn’t find it. I face the same issue once.

Comment: Please add it to the answer. Here is the doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Comment: I have added that to the answer. Can you accept my answer? Thank you

Comment: should add explanation too for clarity.